# "firmware-atheros" network debian package issue while building a minimal OS

Tags: linux, operating-system, debian

Here am experimenting on including firmware-atheros network driver package of Debian flavor of OS. Here goes the command

```
$ sudo mkosi -d debian -r buster -f -b -t gpt_ext4 --checksum --password password --package=vim,curl,git,firmware-atheros,linux-image-amd64 -o image.raw

Error on screen: subprocess.CalledProcessError:.... returned non-zero exit status 100.
```

Let me know what would be the issue when am trying to include the firmware-atheros package? is it in-compatible? or anything else I should include for resolving this conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue if you ever encounter, while working on generating a minimal operating system by using this command **mkosi**. Please include ***--repositories=main,non-free** option*. Since by default it only considers main only.